# Inconsistent display of deleted former moderators on election pages

Tags: support, design, election, deleted-accounts

On [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), the [election page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election) shows two users elected in 2012 whose have 'departed' the site:

[image]

However, [Webmasters' election page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election) shows a rather broken image instead:

[image]

Am I missing something (hence the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag) or is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) which might be fixed by regenerating the page?

Comment: Clearly this is an urgent bug that needs CM attention ASAP. </s>

Comment: @Randal'Thor well, I got their attention in 2 minutes ...

Comment: and a fix in 6-8 minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no real support in the system for handling candidates who get their accounts deleted. So things fall apart.

If anyone notices, I put a tacky placeholder image up and call it good.

Comment: You should have better things to do on a Monday night than solving silly bugs like this :-P

Comment: strictly-speaking, it's Monday *afternoon*, and I'm trying to shake off the lunch lethargy.

Comment: It's Monday evening UTC. And it's dark where I am.

Comment: Well, can't say I agree with living in darkness, but to each their own.

Comment: In the future, what's the preferred avenue of alerting y'all of these incidents? A [bug] post on the site's own Meta? A ping in the Tavern? A post like this?

Comment: Sure, whichever

Comment: Mushrooms like living in darkness... so it can't be all bad.

Comment: One could curse the darkness, or turn on the lights. Post Lunch lethargy on the other hand....