# Moderator missing on election overview page

Tags: support, bug, moderators, election

We have [three moderators on Spanish Language Stack Exchange](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). Yet if you look at the [election page](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election), you only see two of us:

[image]

Why isn't Charlie shown in the results of the first election? That election failed, but that's true for the 2020 election as well, and wimi and I are being shown there.

Comment: Related post (see answer) on Spanish.SE meta: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3181/…

Comment: It's worse at [Physical Fitness.SE](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) where two of the moderators [ran off](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/election) the chart.

Comment: @Rob: [Inconsistency in displaying the results of elections on sites after their first election?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368909/inconsistency-in-displaying-the-results-of-elections-on-sites-after-their-first) ...?

Comment: Whoosh ..  .. ..